# Software for producing tree diagrams with weight on branches

Tags: statistics

I got data I would like to plot in a tree diagram showing the possible pathways and the "Importance" (how often one way occurs), similar to how evolution is often shown.

Is there any kind of software that let's me input different paths and a rating for each path and can visualize this nicely?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any time I hear "statistics" and "software" my mind goes to R.  Googling shows that there is support for tree diagrams, and weighted nodes, but I've only taken basic stats in college and so I don't know if it will suit your needs.  Of course, since it is Open you could make it suit your needs....  :)

Comment: Thanks @ivanivan I've seen that R and different python packages can do it. The results look don't look very nice but more important it doesn't seem possible to automatically change the line thickness for certain paths based on either a given factor or on occurance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve requested functionality with [OrgChart JS](https://balkangraph.com/)

See the screenshot bellow the first links have higher rating

[image]